# MATLAB - reading multiple dat files for loop

Tags: matlab, loops

Hello everyone I'm trying to make a loop file to read several files, this is what I have done so far:

```
anoini = 1980;
anofin = 1981;

mesini = 1;
mesfin = 1;

diai=1;
diaf=1;

nano = (anofin-anoini)+1;


if (mesini == 1) || (mesini == 3) || (mesini == 5) || (mesini == 7) || (mesini == 8) || (mesini == 10) || (mesini == 12)
    lmes = 31;
elseif (mesini == 4) || (mesini == 6) || (mesini == 9) || (mesini == 11)
    lmes = 30;
elseif (mesini == 2)
    lmes = 28;
end


for idia=1:lmes
    for iano = anoini:anofin
        for nn = 1:nano


     D_1{nn,idia} = load(sprintf('F:\\salidas_nam\\%d\\%d%0.2u%0.2u06_NAM_day01.dat',iano,iano,mesini,idia));

        end
    end
end
```

For example I want this two files, but it only seems to read one

```
"F:\salidas_nam\1980\1980010106_NAM_day01.dat"
"F:\salidas_nam\1981\1981010106_NAM_day01.dat"
```

The idea is to automatize this so I can pick which years to read, it is not necesary to use `sprintf`, if someone knows how to do this in another way I will apreciate it.

Comment: As an aside: `any(ismember(mesini,[1 3 5 7 8 10 12]))` would greatly reduce your first `if` statement, same for the second one.

Comment: This is already quite automated right? All you might do is set the two years (start and end? Your variable names aren't helping me here) as inputs to a function in which you wrap the rest, otherwise I don't see a much faster way.

Comment: like @Adriaan said your variable names are confusing me a bit.  However, I think part of the problem is your inner loop.  `nn` in your example loops from 1 to 2.. but `nn` is not used in the building of the data file name.  So it appears you load the same file twice for some reason...

Comment: Ah, Spanish, right, Years, months, days. Note that your setting for February can go wrong, because in leap years February has 29 days, not 28. If you have the aerospace toolbox, there's [`leapyear`](https://mathworks.com/help/aerotbx/ug/leapyear.html) which tells you that.

Comment: Even easier: [`eomday`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eomday.html) looks to be core MATLAB. Gives you for a selected year and month the last day, which is the amount of days in that month.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I actually use and if condition like this
 "mod(iano,4) == 0 && mesini == 2
    lmes = 29;"
It's not really fancy but it works, I'll take a look on leapyear and eomday, thanks!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in your inner loop.  You were iterating over `nn` but not using it in the construction of the filename.  So you ended up loading each file twice:

Therefore your output looked like this (repeated files):

```
D_1{1,1} = F:\salidas_nam\1980\1980010106_NAM_day01.dat
D_1{2,1} = F:\salidas_nam\1980\1980010106_NAM_day01.dat
D_1{1,2} = F:\salidas_nam\1981\1981010106_NAM_day01.dat
D_1{2,2} = F:\salidas_nam\1981\1981010106_NAM_day01.dat
...
```

However, I think you want this (no repeats):

```
D_1{1,1} = F:\salidas_nam\1980\1980010106_NAM_day01.dat
D_1{2,1} = F:\salidas_nam\1981\1981010106_NAM_day01.dat
D_1{1,2} = F:\salidas_nam\1980\1980010206_NAM_day01.dat
D_1{2,2} = F:\salidas_nam\1981\1981010206_NAM_day01.dat
...
```

If that is the case then you can drop the inner `for` loop and do something like this:

```
for idia=1:lmes
    nn = 1;
    for iano = anoini:anofin
        D_1{nn,idia} = load(sprintf('F:\\salidas_nam\\%d\\%d%0.2u%0.2u06_NAM_day01.dat',iano,iano,mesini,idia));
        nn = nn+1;
    end
end
```

This does not address the potential leapyear issues you might have as Adriaan mentioned in the comments.